# Clear modal fields after closing modal

Tags: javascript, c#, twitter-bootstrap

I have this modal

```
<form id="contactModal">
<div id="mymodal2" class="" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">                  
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <span class="modal-title th2" id="lblModalLabel" name="lblModalLabel">Contact</span>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
```

What I want is to clear modal every time its closed so I wrote a script like this:

```
function clear() {
    $("#txtNombreCompleto").val("");
    $("#txtNombreEmpresa").val("");
    $("#exampleInputEmail2").val("");
    $("#dropOficina").val("");
    $("#txtTelefono").val("");
    $("#txtMensaje").val("");
}
$('#mymodal').on('hidden', function(){
    $.clear(this)
});
```

So my inputs inside the modal are something like this:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNombreCompleto" name="txtNombreCompleto" placeholder="Nombre completo">
```

But when I close the modal, it doesn´t run the function, how can I run the function when the modal closes? Regards

Comment: Try this
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    // do something…
})

Comment: I do it, but don´t run, also I put script on console and it works @Sami

Comment: Check your page for JavaScript errors.

Comment: @Sami : put your code inside `$(document).ready(function() { /*... here ....*/ });`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply call `clear();` inside [bootstrap modal `hide.bs.modal` event(or `hidden.bs.modal`)](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) handler or set the function as callback. Also put your code inside [`document ready handler`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for attaching event handler after loading the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mymodal').on('hidden', function() {
    clear()
  });
});
```

---

or get all form all elements inside modal and set value

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mymodal').on('hidden', function() {
    $(':input', this).val('');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thankyou,, my function doesnt works because I don´t have `$(document).ready(function()` to start it. Thanks!

Comment: I have an issue with my code, can you help me please?

Comment: @John : what's the issue?

Comment: I upload my code on my question, the problem is the first function `('mymodal')` runs very well, but my second modal don´t works `('mymodal2')`, also if I run it with console don´t works too, it runs js but don´t works... what can be the problem there?,

Comment: @John :  `mymodal2` is not a valid selector `missing `#` or `.` at beginning

Comment: @John  : it may happen to anyone  :) just remove it from the question itself

Answer (score 2):

I tried this code in my project but it didn't work. So I tried this new code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.btnLogMesaj').click(function () { // your button is clicked
      $('div#demo').empty();  // clear the "div" of the id "demo" 
     *
     * 
     *
  });

     <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="demo">
                    <h4>... Merve's contents </h4>
                </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.